# Ошибка в JS формуле

Tags: javascript

Почему выдает 1.25101 ?

Должно быть 1.25102

```js
function numTick(price, tick) {
    if (parseFloat(tick) == 0) return Number(price);
    let prec = (String(tick).split('.')[1] || '').length;
    let x = (parseInt(price / tick) * tick).toFixed(prec);
    return Number(x);
}
console.log(numTick(1.25102, 0.00001));
```

Comment: `1.25102 / 0.00001 === 125101.99999999999` поэтому когда ты отбрасываешь дробную часть и получаешь неверный ответ в дальнейшем

Comment: @Grundy, а почему? у меня при делении 1.25102 https://disk.yandex.ru/i/ftV3kAGjUqNWCQ . А как это решить можно?

Comment: Потому что ты делишь не в калькуляторе, очевидно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас было лишнее `parseInt`.

```js
function numTick(price, tick) {
    if (parseFloat(tick) == 0) return Number(price);
    let prec = (String(tick).split('.')[1] || '').length;
    let x = ((price / tick) * tick).toFixed(prec); // Вот тут
    return Number(x);
}
console.log(numTick(1.25102, 0.00001));
```

Как подсказал в комментариях @Grundy, можно обойтись без умножения и деления.

```js
function numTick(price, tick) {
    if (parseFloat(tick) == 0) return Number(price);
    let prec = (String(tick).split('.')[1] || '').length;
    let x = price.toFixed(prec); // Вот тут
    return Number(x);
}
console.log(numTick(1.25102, 0.00001));
```

Comment: в принципе, тогда тут и  `/ * ` не нужно. Можно сразу `toFixed` просто использовать

Comment: Я особо не вникал в работу функции, но теперь понял, что хотели сделать, так что думаю да, не нужны тут деления и умножения.